# Oracle Pro*C for insert with a sub select query causing ORA-01403: no data found

Tags: c++, sql, c, oracle, embedded-sql

I am using C++ code with embedded Pro*C (Version: 11.2.0.3.0) for Oracle DB. I am running a bulk insert clause as below:

```
insert int TBL1 (col1, col2) 
select a.col1, b.col2 from TBL2 a, TBL3 b
where a.col1 = :v and a.col2 = b.col2
```

I run this query for a set of records to be inserted, and binding values for `:v` in place.

However, while some records could be inserted, some failed with

```
ORA-01403: no data found
```

I see from `sqlca.sqlerrd[2]`, the number of rows that could be inserted. So, I know M out N records could be inserted. Now, I would like to know which records did fail, so I need a clue of list of all `a.col1` values that could cause this failure.
Is there any way out? Any clue or direction would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit long for a comment.

The error you are referencing is a PL/SQL error, documented [here](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ORA-01403).  This is *not* an error that an `insert` would normally produce.

My one guess is that the table has an insert trigger and this trigger is causing the problem.

It is also possible that your code is in a larger block, and something else in the block is causing the error.

Comment: I know, it's not an insert problem, but caused by the select subquery that couldnot get some matching row for some set of data and while trying to insert through select into, caused this

Comment: `insert . . . select` has no problem with a `select` that returns no rows.

Comment: My guess is that the subquery that has a select is run as select into ... variable and then used that variable for insert, and select into causing no data found

Comment: @DebasishJana . . . `select into` is allowed in a subquery?

Comment: no but getting translated to by Pro*C, I presume, as I am getting this trouble